# Cannot set cookie in iframe using the Storage Access API on Safari

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari, storage-access-api

I have an iframe on my page. As Safari blocks 3rd party cookies, I am trying to use the Storage Access API as suggested here under 'Developer Guidance': https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/. I have copied the following code from [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_Access_API/Using#Accessing_a_user's_cookies_in_an_embedded_cross-origin_iframe):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    document.getElementById('test-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
      document.hasStorageAccess().then(hasAccess => {
        console.log('hasAccess: ' + hasAccess);
        if (!hasAccess) {
          return document.requestStorageAccess();
        }
      }).then(_ => {
        console.log('Now we have first-party storage access!');
        document.cookie = "foo=bar";
        console.log(`document.cookie: ${document.cookie}`);
      }).catch(_ => {
        console.log('error');
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<button id="test-button">Test</button>
```

Browser console output:

```
[Log] hasAccess: true
[Log] Now we have first-party storage access!
[Log] document.cookie:
```

As you can see, the grant seems to be successful but still cannot set the cookie. Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Safari Version 13.0.1

**EDIT:** Console output on Safari 13.1:

```
[Log] hasAccess: false
[Log] error
```

**Note:** The enclosing page is a simple `iframe` tag with a `src` pointing to this page.

Comment: I have the same issue. Storage access seems to give access to existing cookies but won't store any new ones. This applies to using "document.cookie" as well as new cookies returned in the "Set-Cookie" header. The documentation seems to say it should work, but it does not.

Comment: With Safari 13.1 the request is rejected but I couldn't understand why.

Comment: Yes, it's really frustrating. BTW Safari 13.1 began behave the same, it seems to give access but setting cookies fails.

Comment: As [this article specifies](https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/) there are some rules to grant access. And, shouldn't `console.log('Now we have first-party storage access!');` come in the `then` of `requestStorageAccess()`?

Comment: @SupunKavinda The first 3 rules doesn't apply here. I don't completely understand Rule 5. Maybe it's referring to some other mechanism which have blacklisted the domain. I don't think this applies either but I will try a few things to see if that's related.

Comment: I do not have a direct answer for you, but I have personally found that attempting to nest calls to `requestStorageAccess` inside a promise from `hasStorageAccess` does not work. 
 Others seem to have reported the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53877737 That won't help with your issue, but may unblock you if you're hitting the triggered-by-user-gesture rule.

Comment: @DavidBrooks Yes, I found the same. I'm not sure about the reason. But, what I did was always calling `requestStorageAccess`. So, if user needs access, browser will prompt (in safari).

Comment: @lunr were you able to figure out a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR

Make sure a cookie has already been set for the domain in a first-party context.

---

There's a couple of things to look out for with that code sample. Please note the following was tested on Safari 13.1.

### Conditions of a user prompt, and subsequent access grant:

1. `document.requestStorageAccess` has to be called as a result of a user action. Despite as documented on the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_Access_API#Storage_Access_API_methods), `document.hasStorageAccess` does not seem to propagate the user action.
2. The user must have interacted with the third party in a first party context already. Any click on the document will do.

### Conditions of being able to write a cookie:

A cookie must have already been set on the domain in a first party context. This cookie can either be set by the server as a response header, or by JS using document.cookie. With a bit of further testing, it seems this cookie MUST NOT be set with the domain flag in order for a subsequent cookie to be set in the third party context. This means that in effect, the existing cookie must also be set on the same exact sub domain.

Comment: Cookies work taking these conditions into account. But it looks like you have to request access each time, so we find this unusable for now. Maybe we were still doing something else wrong. In any case, we decide to do this differently. Thanks.

Comment: @lunr can you share the result?

Comment: @here I have the same issue. Is there any way we can set the cookies or not in IFrame.

Comment: I can't really decide if the implementation or the documentation of Safaris StorageAccessAPI is worse. At least both are crap. That's obvious.

Comment: Is "2. The user must have interacted with the third party in a first-party context already." the intended behaviour? Seems like building any kind of first-time customer-facing interaction/purchase flow is out of the question if that is the case.

Comment: @marc_thomas Yes it is the intention. You can read more about the motivations here: https://github.com/privacycg/storage-access. In particular "The Storage Access API is not intended to grant arbitrary third-parties cookie access. It is only intended to grant cookie access to third parties that the user actively uses as first party too, i.e. websites the user recognizes and uses." You can incorporate the opening of a popup (i.e. opening your site in a first-party context) into your flow.

Comment: @SergeyKorzhov Have you found a solution for this problem? I run into the same problem and got stuck trying to set the first cookie as explained.